# JPanel disappearing from window

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jdialog

The SSCCE below is a class that extends `JPanel`. The `JPanel` is the basic outline of a calendar (I've stripped it way down for simplicity's sake), and it consists of `JButton` components, a `JLabel`, and a `JTable`. When I add this frame to a window (i.e. `JDialog`), it appears as normal. However, when I add another component with it, it disappears. Why is this happening, and how can I make this not happen?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CalendarPanel extends JPanel {

    private static JDialog dialog = new JDialog();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    setDialogProperties();
    addComponentsToDialog();
    dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void setDialogProperties() {
    dialog.setModal(true);
    dialog.setResizable(false);
    dialog.setSize(new Dimension(330, 400));
    dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(2);
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private static void addComponentsToDialog() {
    CalendarPanel calendar = new CalendarPanel();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(calendar);

    dialog.add(panel);
    //dialog.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel lblMonth;
    private JButton btnPrev, btnNext;
    private JTable tblCalendar;
    private DefaultTableModel mtblCalendar;
    private JScrollPane stblCalendar;
    private static GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    private GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    public CalendarPanel() {

    super(gridBag);

    createControls();
    addControlsToPanel();
    addHeaders();
    setTableProperties();
    }

    private void createControls() {
    lblMonth = new JLabel("January");
    btnPrev = new JButton("<");
    btnNext = new JButton(">");
    mtblCalendar = new DefaultTableModel() {

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int mColIndex) {
        return false;
        }
    };
    tblCalendar = new JTable(mtblCalendar);
    stblCalendar = new JScrollPane(tblCalendar);
    stblCalendar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 247));
    }

    private void addControlsToPanel() {
    GridBagLayout topGridBag = new GridBagLayout();

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(topGridBag);

    JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel();
    labelPanel.add(lblMonth);
    labelPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 20));

    constraints.gridx = 1;
    topGridBag.setConstraints(labelPanel, constraints);

    constraints.gridx = 2;
    topGridBag.setConstraints(btnNext, constraints);

    topPanel.add(btnPrev);
    topPanel.add(labelPanel);
    topPanel.add(btnNext);

    gridBag.setConstraints(topPanel, constraints);

    constraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBag.setConstraints(stblCalendar, constraints);

    this.add(topPanel);
    this.add(stblCalendar);
    }

    private void addHeaders() {
    String[] headers = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        mtblCalendar.addColumn(headers[i]);
    }
    }

    private void setTableProperties() {
    tblCalendar.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

    tblCalendar.setRowHeight(38);
    mtblCalendar.setColumnCount(7);
    mtblCalendar.setRowCount(6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDialogs and all top-level windows use BorderLayout by default. When you add a component to it (actually its contentPane) without specifying the position, you add it to the BorderLayout.CENTER position by default. You are covering up the previously added component whenever you add a new one. You will want to learn about the layouts available for your use and then use them to their best advantage.

e.g.,

```
  dialog.add(panel);
  dialog.add(new JLabel("Hello", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Next you'll want to avoid setting the sizes of anything and to be sure to `pack()` your top level windows that allow this.